# How to allow to add gradients to core/heading block?

Tags: block-editor

is there a way to add gradients support for background in the core/heading block?

I've tried to

- extend `settings.supports` with `gradients: true`
- add gradients to theme json:

```
"blocks": {
      "core/heading": {
        "color": {
          "gradients": [
            {
              "slug": "dark-gradient-with-stripes",
              "name": "Dark gradient with stripes",
              "gradient": "linear-gradient(to left bottom, rgba(125, 134, 152, .2) 15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 92.5%)"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
```

Your help is really appreciated.

Comment: to the text or the background? Have you tried wrapping it in a cover or group block?

Comment: To the background. I don't want to wrap it I'd rather modify the block settings - it's a custom design and it would be not too user-friendly. And to be honest, why I can set up a solid background, but not a gradient? It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: because nobody implemented the gradient, the options in `theme.json` aren't generic interchangeable features that can be applied to any block, and declaring that a block has gradient support in `theme.json` doesn't enable or insert that functionality into a block, code needs writing at the other end to read and use that configuration, it's purely a configuration file

Comment: Yeah, I see, that's the problem of Gutenberg - every component is developed on its own instead of having a source class with those features that will be applied to the child component... I'll note it down, if I have some remaining time on the project, I'll try to add it to core/heading block.

Comment: blocks already share a lot of components, but what you seek is not feasible, and in some cases undesirable, as I mentioned assemble/compose your blocks, don't modify them. One could argue the solution here if UX is a concern is to provide a block pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, currently gradient support in the heading block has not been implemented.

You can declare that it supports it in theme.json or via `supports`, but there is nothing in the block to read that data in and use it. Gradient support has to be built into a block, it can't be inserted arbitrarily.

The closest you can get is with predefined variants or styles, a custom block, or wrapper the heading in a group/cover block. **Composition not modification.**